# Google Play Services integration error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have installed on my computer eclipse and then I have installed all versions of google play services from sdk manager. Later I have imported it to eclipse with "copy projects into workspace" option. It is imported to the eclipse but there are some errors on values folders. I am attaching the image view of the project explorer.

[image: google play services values error]

Comment: have you tried refreshing the project; then perform a build of the project?. have you copied the project into your workspace?

Comment: just remove all language folder except your language folder

Comment: Close eclipse and run it again.

Comment: have you clean project?

Comment: I have deleted and imported again restarted the eclipse. But now I have other problems at other projects: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY